# What do the numbers on Alexa's Page View Charts mean?

Tags: analytics, alexa

I didn't understand the values of the chart -page-views ([google stats](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/google.com)).

For example, for google, what mean these values ?

4.84300   -0.6%

Millions, billions of visits?

In my case, I want to know how many visits the site have per day (average)

Answer (score 1):

Alexa measures traffic in *relative* terms, not absolutes. The values mean Google.com's page views accounted for 4.834% of total page views of Google.com. The -0.6% indicates that there was a drop of  0.6% of page views in comparison to the previous day.

Alexa doesn't measure page views in terms of visits per day - to get that information consider using [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) or [Mint Stats](http://haveamint.com/).